# Joomla 3.0 menu fatal error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

After trying to add a menu item to a menu in the backend of Joomla 3.0 that failed due to a duplicate alias accessing the menu section of the backend no longer works.
Menu items disappear from the frontend.
Trying to add further menu items results in a fatal error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36324 bytes) in \libraries\joomla\table\nested.php on line 1251
```

deleting the erroneous menu item in the database returns the frontend menu items, but the backend is still not working.

this is the method highlighted in the above error: with **** highlighting the row

```
/**
 * Method to recursively rebuild the whole nested set tree.
 *
 * @param   integer  $parentId  The root of the tree to rebuild.
 * @param   integer  $leftId    The left id to start with in building the tree.
 * @param   integer  $level     The level to assign to the current nodes.
 * @param   string   $path      The path to the current nodes.
 *
 * @return  integer  1 + value of root rgt on success, false on failure
 *
 * @link    http://docs.joomla.org/JTableNested/rebuild
 * @since   11.1
 * @throws  RuntimeException on database error.
 */
public function rebuild($parentId = null, $leftId = 0, $level = 0, $path = '')
{
    // If no parent is provided, try to find it.
    if ($parentId === null)
    {
        // Get the root item.
        $parentId = $this->getRootId();
        if ($parentId === false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Build the structure of the recursive query.
    if (!isset($this->_cache['rebuild.sql']))
    {
        $query = $this->_db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($this->_tbl_key . ', alias')
            ->from($this->_tbl)
            ->where('parent_id = %d');

        // If the table has an ordering field, use that for ordering.
        if (property_exists($this, 'ordering'))
        {
            $query->order('parent_id, ordering, lft');
        }
        else
        {
            $query->order('parent_id, lft');
        }
        $this->_cache['rebuild.sql'] = (string) $query;
    }

    // Make a shortcut to database object.

    // Assemble the query to find all children of this node.
    $this->_db->setQuery(sprintf($this->_cache['rebuild.sql'], (int) $parentId));

    $children = $this->_db->loadObjectList();

    // The right value of this node is the left value + 1
    $rightId = $leftId + 1;

    // Execute this function recursively over all children
    foreach ($children as $node)
    {
        /*
         * $rightId is the current right value, which is incremented on recursion return.
         * Increment the level for the children.
         * Add this item's alias to the path (but avoid a leading /)
         */
   ****
        $rightId = $this->rebuild($node->{$this->_tbl_key}, $rightId, $level + 1, $path . (empty($path) ? '' : '/') . $node->alias);
   ****

        // If there is an update failure, return false to break out of the recursion.
        if ($rightId === false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // We've got the left value, and now that we've processed
    // the children of this node we also know the right value.
    $query = $this->_db->getQuery(true);
    $query->update($this->_tbl)
        ->set('lft = ' . (int) $leftId)
        ->set('rgt = ' . (int) $rightId)
        ->set('level = ' . (int) $level)
        ->set('path = ' . $this->_db->quote($path))
        ->where($this->_tbl_key . ' = ' . (int) $parentId);
    $this->_db->setQuery($query)->execute();

    // Return the right value of this node + 1.
    return $rightId + 1;
}
```

does anyone have a fix?

the docs article linked in the method details is effectively non-existent.

**edit1: Notes:**

- This is on IIS on localhost for dev purposes
- set memory limit to 256m and 512m but no change.
- changed several other time/size limit settings in PHP.ini but still no joy
- restarted server.
- no cookies
- rebuilt menus and modules - fixes front end display - backend still broken.

**edit2: Current settings:**

```
max_execution_time: 3000 3000
max_file_uploads: 200 200
max_input_nesting_level 64 64
max_input_time 600 600
max_input_vars 1000 1000
memory_limit -1 512M
```

**edit3: db row content in the #_menu table:**

```
  '0', 'menutype', 'title', 'alias', '', '', '', 'separator', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '1', '', '0', '{\"menu_image\":\"\",\"menu_text\":1}', '223', '224', '0', '*', '0'
```

**edit4: further discovery:**

If for example alias is 'abc123'  every other record in the #_menu table has its path field updated to abc123/existing-alias, whilst path remains empty on new row added by trying to add menu item with alias abc123, this row has an id of 0.

Comment: Did you check the Joomla config to see what the memory limit set in it was?

Comment: nothing in the config for joomla about memory limit, overridden the php.ini to -1 as notes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the primary key was missing from the menu_type and menu tables and this was causing the timeout - fatal error

Comment: I have the exact same error, although the primary keys are indeed there.

Comment: might be a stupid comment but the fields/values were there, but are they set as primary key fields in your db?

Comment: Yes, they are marked as primary keys in the database.